# PC freezes during startup at BIOS screen. Motherboard problem?

Tags: bios

I don't know if this is a problem with a sort of general solution or not, but I'll be happy to edit this to include any system specs necessary.

When I turn on my computer it tends to freeze at the BIOS screen. Curiously enough, after I hit Tab, it halts for a moment displaying the Memory Test line then "Primary Master" appears for a split second before some letters vanish from the screen. That is to say, "Primary Master" turns into " rim ry M st r" or something crazy. A number of letters disappear from the other words in such a manner simultaneously and the computer freezes at this point.

I generally have to restart several times before it goes through the BIOS normally. Even when this happens, the green Vista loading bar freezes for a minute or so at several different positions before the computer finishes booting to my desktop.

S.O.S.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like a memory issue, but it could very well be the motherboard. First I'd give it a [memtest](http://www.memtest.org/) run. See if you can get through it without errors. If you have multiple memory modules, you could also try booting with only 1 at a time in. See which stick(s) gives you problems and which don't. For good measure, run a chkdsk once you boot into Vista.

Comment: I've booted it before with one stick at a time (I have four 1GB sticks) with the same results as above. Memtest86+ found no errors.

The BIOS screen says my installed memory is 1024K larger than my OK memory, if that is indicative of anything.

Comment: Memory may not be the culprit, I'd grab UltimateBootCD ( http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/ ) and perform some diagnostic tests.

Comment: @ John T - Which ones?

Answer (score 0):

Before you conclude, you first have to replace the memory with a working memory form a defrent computer, or from the shop and try booting it again.

If the problem stills remain, then I am sorry, it will be your mobo. You need to change your motherboard.